# Solutions to fourth order PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

I'm interested in finding analytic solutions to this PDE:

$$-\frac{s^3}{xyz} \frac{\partial^4}{\partial s^4} H(s,x,y,z) -\frac{3s^2}{xyz} \frac{\partial^3}{\partial s^3} H(s,x,y,z) -\frac{s}{xyz} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2} H(s,x,y,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} H(s,x,y,z)$$

I searched the literature pretty thoroughly but didn't find what I was looking for. I'm hoping to apply this equation and its solutions to a related problem I'm working on.

> Can anyone point me to a reference for this equation or a solution method?

Comment: Separation of variables? Assume $x,y,z > 0$:

For each $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ you can take the ansatz
$$ H(s,x,y,z) = h_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(s) x^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma $$
and you can find $h_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(s)$ by integrating
$$  (s^3 \frac{d^4}{ds^4} + 3 s^2 \frac{d^3}{ds^3} + s \frac{d^2}{ds^2} + \alpha\beta\gamma) h_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma}(s) = 0 $$ The ODE can be solved by power series.